# ssrs secondary parameter won't run until pushing view report button even though its primary parameters have default values

Tags: reporting-services

I have a parameter (secondary) that depends on other parameters (primary). When those primary parameters have default values, the secondary parameter won't be activated until the view report button is pressed. In order to run the report, the report button needs to be pushed again. Is it by design or can be changed? Thank you.

Comment: I've used cascading parameters with and without defaults for years without any problems. Can you give more into on how the parameter available items and default items get populated. Please your SQL and/or function used for the parameters. Please also give some examples. For instance I often have two parameters to select a country, the first will be continent, the 2nd country (filtered to just those in the chosen continent). Also please let me know what version of SSRS you are using and what development tools (Visual Studio or Report Builder)

Comment: In my case, primary parameters have some default values. Because of that, if the secondary parameters use the primary parameters for its default values, it should be activated (just like the primary parameters) when the report is lunched (without pressing the view report button), right? The question is how?  ,

Comment: It should work like that but depending on how you are populating the 2nd parameter, I'm not sure what the problem is. Could you post the code/expressions/sql that you use to populate you parameters.

Comment: I found out that it depends on the secondary parameter query. If that query needs a long time to run, it won't be activated until the view report button is pushed, which gives it some extra time to run. If the secondary parameter query is easy to run, it won't be a problem. Is there a way to configure the report server to complete the running?

Comment: I've not come across that before so I can;t really help. The queries to populate parameter lists are normally quick. Not sure if you can optimise the query or if the data is not updated frequently, run a job on a schedule each night to build a table that contains your parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is by design. I have struggled with this for many years as well. If anyone else comes across a way, I would love to know as well.